# Is the term "downforce" exclusively used to describe the aerodynamics phenomenon?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests, phrase-usage

When describing a literal, physically applied "downward force", would it be improper to use "downforce" rather than "down force" (or some variant of)?  And if so, should it be hyphenated, i.e., "down-force", or is there a term that fits better altogether?

Comment: I would restrict my use to (i) *downforce* = a force produced as air passes over the surfaces of a moving object so as to press the object against the surface upon which it travels (ii) *downwards force* - the force, or component of a force, that acts downwards.

Comment: That's what I had intuited, but wasn't sure if there's an actual convention or rule that addresses this?

Comment: @Arctiic - Rules?  This is English!!